# Error reading 'nom' on type dao.Etudiant_$$_jvst1a2_0 Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, search

I want to search on a table by ID , the search work fine , but when  hibernate don t find any row it s return this error :
    **Error reading "nom" on type dao.Etudiant**  , and sometimes it s return :   **No row with the given identifier exists:[dao.Etudiant#4]**
I want to show nothing when hibernate don t find  that ID on the table , need your helps thanks , I m stack my learning, I googled a lot without any solution. this is my code :

Controller :

```
package controller;import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.omg.CORBA.Request;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import dao.DaoEtudiant;
import dao.Etudiant;
import service.EtudiantMetier;

@Controller
public class EtudiantController {

@Autowired
EtudiantMetier service;
@RequestMapping("afficherId")
public String afficheId(Model mod,@RequestParam(value="id") Long id)
{
    List <Etudiant> ets1=new ArrayList<Etudiant>();
    ets1.add(service.chercheEtudiantID(id));
    mod.addAttribute("etudiants",ets1);
    return "etudiant1";
}
}
```

Class : Etudiant :

```
package dao;

import java.util.Date;

public class Etudiant {

private Long idEtudiant;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private Date dateNaissance;
private String email;


public Etudiant() {
    super();

}
public Long getIdEtudiant() {
    return idEtudiant;
}
public void setIdEtudiant(Long idEtudiant) {
    this.idEtudiant = idEtudiant;
}
public Etudiant(String nom, String prenom, Date dateNaissance, String email) {
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    this.email = email;
}
public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}
public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
public Date getDateNaissance() {
    return dateNaissance;
}
public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
    this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

Etudiant.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Oct 20, 2016 7:42:26 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="dao.Etudiant" table="etudiant">
    <id name="idEtudiant">
        <column name="ID_ETUDIANT" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="nom" column="NOM" />
    <property name="prenom" >
        <column name="PRENOM" />
    </property>
    <property name="dateNaissance" >
        <column name="DATE_NAISSANCE" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" >
        <column name="EMAIL" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property    

    name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/etudes</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">100</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>


    <property  name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"  >
     true
    </property>

    <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
    <mapping resource="dao/Etudiant.hbm.xml"/>



</session-factory>
```

Etudiantmetierimpl.java:

```
@Override
public Etudiant chercheEtudiantID(Long idEtudiant) {
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("avant  load  session");
    Etudiant et=session.load  (Etudiant.class, idEtudiant);

    //Etudiant et=session.get  (Etudiant.class, idEtudiant); // presque meme chose que load 

    System.out.println("apres load session  et  ");

    session.close();
    return et;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find it finally. I change this line :

```
 Etudiant et=session.load  (Etudiant.class, idEtudiant)
```

to :

```
 Etudiant et=session.get  (Etudiant.class, idEtudiant)
```

doc:

**session.load()**
•   It will always return a “proxy” (Hibernate term) without hitting the database. In Hibernate, proxy is an object with the given identifier value, its properties are not initialized yet, it just look like a temporary fake object.
•   If no row found , it will throws an ObjectNotFoundException.

**session.get()**
•   It always hit the database and return the real object, an object that represent the database row, not proxy.
•   If no row found , it return null.